# "grep"ing first 12 of last 24 character from a line

Tags: shell, sed, awk, grep

I am trying to extract "first 12 of last 24 character" from a line, i.e.,
for a line:

```
species,subl,cmp=    1    4    1    s1,torque= 0.41207E-09-0.45586E-13
```

I need to extract "0.41207E-0".
(I have not written the code, so don't curse me for its formatting. )

I have managed to do this via:

```
  var_s=`grep "species,subl,cmp=    $3    $4    $5" $tfile |sed -n '$s/.*\(........................\)$/\1/p'|sed -n '$s/\(............\).*$/\1/p'`
```

but, is there any more readable way of doing this, rather then counting dots?

**EDIT**
Thanks to both of you;
so, I have sed,awk grep and bash.
I will run that in loop, for 100's of file.
so, can you also suggest me which one is most efficient, wrt time?

Comment: Haven't benchmarked anything but I tend to believe that pure bash solution should be fastest since it doesn't invoke any external binary.

Comment: Don't pre-optimize.. Only optimize when speed becomes a problem. The best solution is the one you understand the most and feel most comfortable extending yourself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way with `GNU sed` *(without counting dots)*:

```
$ sed -r 's/.*(.{11}).{12}/\1/' file
0.41207E-09
```

Similarly with `GNU grep`:

```
$ grep -Po '.{11}(?=.{12}$)' file
0.41207E-09
```

Perhaps a `python` solution may also be helpful:

```
python -c 'import sys;print "\n".join([a[-24:-13] for a in sys.stdin])' < file
0.41207E-09
```

I'm not sure your example data and question match up so just change the values in the `{n}` quantifier accordingly.

Comment: +1 for 3 interesting options. Just a note that on OSX replace `sed -r` with `sed -E`

Comment: @anubhava you may be interested in this undocumented features of `GNU sed` that `-E` is an alias for `-r` unfortunately this is not the case the other way round.

Comment: Oh yes I came to know about it after installing gnu sed on my OSX last month using `home brew`

Comment: Thanks for GREP solution ! It saves me loooong listing of logs with Base64 encode images.

Answer (score 4):

Simplest is using pure bash:

```
echo "${str:(-24):12}"
```

OR awk can also do that:

```
awk '{print substr($0, length($0)-23, 12)}' <<< $str
```

#### OUTPUT:

0.41207E-09

**EDIT:** For using bash solution on a file:

```
while read l; do echo "${l:(-24):12}"; done < file
```

Comment: +1 for the `bash` solution, it would be useful to show how to extended it's use with files.

Comment: @sudo_O: Thanks, for using it file I guess a while loop will be required for bash solution. (which can be avoided in sed, grep, awk etc)

Answer (score 2):

Another one, less efficient but has the advantage of making you discover new tools

```
`echo "$str" | rev | cut -b 1-24 | rev | cut -b 1-12
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use awk to get first 12 characters of last 24 characters from a line:

```
awk '{substr($0,(length($0)-23))};{print substr($0,(length($0)-10))}' myfile.txt
```

Comment: You can easily do this in a single invocation of `awk`; piping the output of `awk` to another `awk` is wasteful.